# Cannot find html element using css or xpath selectors in Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors, scrapy-shell

I'm using Scrapy to scrape this [website](https://www.crn.com/rankings-and-lists/wotc2023.htm?st1=1&st2=a#searchresults&itc=refresh). I want to grab all the div elements with class="data1". I'm using css and xpath selectors to do so. However, I cannot find these elements using css and xpath selectors even though I can see them in the html code in the browser.

In the scrapy shell after fetching the url:

```
In [6]: response.css('div#my_div')
Out[6]: [<Selector query="descendant-or-self::div[@id = 'my_div']" data='<div id="my_div">Results will be show...'>]

In [7]: response.css('div#my_div div')
Out[7]: []

In [8]: response.xpath('//div[@class="data1"]')
Out[8]: []
```

The html looks something like this:

```
<div id="my_div" style>
 <div class="data1">...</div>
 <div class="data1">...</div>
 <div class="data1">...</div>
 ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because that portion of the site is rendered with javascript.  You can see this if you were to call `.get()` on your first query in your example:

```
In [1]: response.css('div#my_div').get()

Out[1]: '<div id="my_div">Results will be shown here.</div>'
```

If you investigate by looking in the network tab of the browser developer tools you can discover that all that information is coming from an api call to `'https://data.crn.com/2023/wotc2023.php?st1=1&st2=a'` which when fetched via scrapy shell returns a `json` object with all the information in that section.

```
In [3]: fetch('https://data.crn.com/2023/wotc2023.php?st1=1&st2=a')
2023-05-08 20:57:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://data.crn.com/2023/wotc2023.php?st1=1&st2=a> (referer: None)

In [4]: response.json()
Out[4]: 
[{'Pkey': '617',
  'Company': 'F5',
  'Name_First': 'Barbara',
  'Name_Last': 'Abboud',
  'Image': 'f5-abboud-barbara.jpg'},
 {'Pkey': '1208',
  'Company': 'Samsung Electronics America',
  'Name_First': 'Shpresa',
  'Name_Last': 'Abdullaj',
  'Image': 'samsung-electronics-america-abdullaj-shpresa.jpg'},
 {'Pkey': '499',
  'Company': 'Davenport Group',
  'Name_First': 'Kim',
  'Name_Last': 'Abrams',
  'Image': 'davenport-group-abrams-kim.jpg'},
 {'Pkey': '35',
  'Company': 'Alteryx',
  'Name_First': 'Daniella',
  'Name_Last': 'Aburto Valle',
  'Image': 'alteryx-aburto-valle-daniella.jpg'},
  .......]
```